# MySQL: information_schema.columns bugs?

Tags: php, mysql, information-schema

Why `information_schema.columns` always duplicates the result? For instance,

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name = 'root_blocks'
```

I will get this,

```
column_name

blc_id
blc_email
cat_id
blc_created
blc_updated
blc_id
blc_email
cat_id
blc_created
blc_updated
```

The duplicates go unpredictable on other tables when I try to query through phpmyadmin.

How can I make it not to duplicate?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: What version of MySQL Server & Client?

Comment: MySQL client version: mysqlnd 5.0.7. i'm on wamp server...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name = 'root_blocks'
AND `table_schema` = 'SCHEMA_NAME'
```

Please try this.

If you would like to select from all the database and get the unique column names then please try this..

```
SELECT DISTINCT(column_name) 
    FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE table_name = 'root_blocks'
```

Comment: yea just did. but it return zero result now...:(

Comment: did you replaced with your schema name on the place of 'SCHEMA_NAME'?

Comment: no didn't - I think that is the reason why it doesnt work. how do I know what my schema name is?? thanks.

Comment: if not you dont know the schema name please try this SELECT DISTINCT(column_name) 
    FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE table_name = 'root_blocks'

Comment: yes got the result with `SELECT DISTINCT` but I also got a warning - `unknown table status: TABLE_TYPE`. why?

Comment: Can I have the compeleted query that you executed?

Comment: @karthink: that is my complete query. just realised that `table_schema` is my db name! lol but I still don't know why I have this warning. please see my edit above. thanks.

Comment: the warning is no way related to the query that you executed as far as i now. I am not very sure about the warning, it could be something with the phpmyadmin config. In that case the warning should appear all the time no matter if you execute any query or not. warnings dont harm your code unless you are too concerned about the performance.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have the same table in multiple schemas?

What happens if you run:

```
SELECT table_schema, column_name 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name = 'root_blocks'
```

Comment: I think I have other databases with the same table structure, names, etc, that causes the duplicates. so how can I target particular database only?? thanks.

Comment: @lauthiamkok: Do you see different values in the schema column? The database might also show up in the table_catalog column but I'm not sure about that

Comment: @lauthiamkok: I just checked: the database name shows up in table_schema, so just add a WHERE clause to limit that to the database in question.

Comment: yea got it thanks. but I got a warning which I don't understand it... please see my edit above.

Comment: @lauthiamkok: No idea. I don't know that SQL client you are using